# CNOT error rate of 1 in IBM backends

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-quantum-devices

I have noticed that some CNOT gates (for instance, between qubits 1 and 2 in `ibmq_casablanca`) display an error rate of 1 while typical error rates are of course much smaller. How is that even possible? What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great observation!

The devices are calibrated daily(ish) and sometimes a bad calibration requires a "rerun". The value 1 is some sort of flag that something went wrong with the calibration.

[image: casablanca calibration values with connection 1_2 = 1]

Noise-aware transpilation algorithms will try to avoid that gate as will be presented as particularly noisy.

Thanks @paul-nation for the help answering this question!

Comment: Nice (+1). That is a clever way to help the transpiler to distinguish and ignore faulty qubits.